# Copy unsigned char array

Tags: c, string, strcpy, unsigned-char

What would be the best way to copy unsigned char array to another?

For example:

```
unsigned char q[1000];
unsigned char p[1000];

strcpy (q,&p);
```

The above code does not work, it gives me error saying "cannot convert parameter 1 from unsigned char [1000] to char *".

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean to tag this question `c++` and not `c`? There should be no problem using `strcpy` with `unsigned char` arrays (as long as they're null-terminated) in C. At worst an off-by-default warning.

Comment: It does not matter if it is C or C++, using the &operator is always a bug here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As indicated by its name, [`strcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy) works on C string (which a unsigned char array is not).

You should consider [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy).

Comment: You can cast an unsigned char* to char*.

Comment: Can you provide a small example as I am having problems with copying an unsigned char variable to an unsigned char array using memcpy.  `passing argument 2 of ‘memcpy’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
`